# Выпадающее меню не слушается

Tags: css, css3

Попросили поправить чужой код, однако на одном месте застопорился. Выпадающее меню отображается не так как нужно: отображаются как при flex-direction: column, мне же нужно вывести их в одну строку, чтобы был пункт, снизу все его подпункты, справа следующий пункт меню с его подпунктами.

Стили не слушаются, перепробовал много вариантов, ничего не помогает. Уверен что-то не вижу.

**HTML структура меню:**

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-menu__item item-120">
        <a href="/o-kompanii">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-menu__item item-184 deeper main-menu__item--parent">
        <a href="#">Продукция</a>
        <ul class="main-menu-submenu unstyled small ">
            <li class="main-menu__item item-185 active deeper main-menu__item--parent">
                <a href="/filtry-dlya-ochistnykh-sooruzhenij">Фильтры для очистных сооружений</a>
                <ul class="main-menu-submenu unstyled small ">
                    <li class="main-menu__item item-187">
                        <a href="/osvetlitelnye-sorbtsionnye">Фильтры напорные осветлительные сорбционные</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item item-189">
                        <a href="/glubokoj-ochistki">Фильтры напорные глубокой очистки</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item item-188">
                        <a href="/kombinirovannye">Фильтры безнапорные комбинированные</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item item-190">
                        <a href="/glubokoj-ochistki">Фильтры безнапорные глубокой очистки </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item item-186 deeper main-menu__item--parent">
                <a href="/filtry-dlya-nasosnykh-stantsij">Фильтры для насосных станций</a>
                <ul class="main-menu-submenu unstyled small ">
                <li class="main-menu__item item-191">
                    <a href="/produktsiya/category-2/filtr-ov-5">Фильтр ОВ-5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu__item item-192">
                    <a href="/produktsiya/category-2/ezhektor-s-konicheskoj-nasadkoj">Эжектор с конической насадкой</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-menu__item item-127">
        <a href="/sertifikaty">Сертификаты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-menu__item item-119">
        <a href="/kontakty">Контакты</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;

}

.main-nav__close {
  display: none;
}

.main-menu > .main-menu__item {
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.main-menu > .main-menu__item:hover {
}

.main-menu > .main-menu__item a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.main-menu a::after {
  z-index: 10000;
position: absolute;
left: 8px;
//bottom: -1px;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 0px;
transition: all 0.3s;
content: '';
height: 2px;
background: #fc6a20;
}
.main-menu  a:hover::after {
width: 25px;
}

.main-menu-submenu a::after {
  left: 23px;
}

.main-menu > .main-menu__item a:hover {

}

.main-menu > .main-menu__item.active {
}

.main-menu__item--parent {
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu-submenu {

  top: 100%;
  left: 0;

  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  
  min-width: 16rem;

  padding: .5rem 0;

  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  

  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);

}


/* Заголовки в подменю в каталоге (синенькие) */
.main-menu__item--parent > .main-menu-submenu > .main-menu__item > a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: block;

}

/* Серые кнопки подменю в каталоге */
.main-menu__item--parent > .main-menu-submenu > .main-menu__item > .main-menu-submenu a {
  background: #fff;
  /* padding: .6rem 1.5rem; */
}


.main-menu__item.item-127--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-128--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-149--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-162--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-175--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-200--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-225--parent > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-127 > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-128 > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-149 > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-162 > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-175 > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-200 > a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-225 > a:after{
    /* top: 8px;
    right: 9px;
    font-size: 11px;
    content: "\f105";
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome; */
    display: none;
}



.main-menu-submenu > .main-menu__item:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover > .main-menu-submenu {
  position: absolute;

  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;

  min-width: 20rem;
}

.main-menu__item--parent > .main-menu-submenu {
  min-width: 20rem;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover > .main-menu-submenu:hover {
}

.main-menu__item.item-123:hover > .main-menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  width: 94rem;
  height: 51rem;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #777;
  margin-left: -20rem
}

.main-menu__item.item-123 > .main-menu-submenu {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*
.main-menu__item.item-123 > .main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item > a {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
} */

.main-menu__item.item-123:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123 .main-menu-submenu {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123 > .main-menu-submenu:hover {
  background: inherit;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123 > .main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu.small {
  position: static;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: auto;
  width: 16rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123 > .main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu.small .main-menu__item {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #05a3cb;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover > .main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .6rem 1.5rem;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover > .main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  //left: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover .main-menu-submenu {
display: block;
}

/*** Меню гамбургер ***/

.menu-hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: .5rem;
  right: .5rem;

  display: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;

  width: 50px;
  height: 38px;

  padding: 8px;

  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);

  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;

       -o-transition-timing-function: linear;

          transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .15s;
       -o-transition-duration: .15s;
          transition-duration: .15s;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity,-webkit-filter;
  transition-property: opacity,-webkit-filter;
  -o-transition-property: opacity,filter;
  transition-property: opacity,filter;
  transition-property: opacity,filter,-webkit-filter;

  z-index: 10;

  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-hamburger__lines,
.menu-hamburger__lines::before,
.menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  position: absolute;

  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;

  background: #033071;

  border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;

  transition-property: -webkit-transform;

  -o-transition-property: transform;

  transition-property: transform;

  transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;

  -webkit-transition: .275s;

  -o-transition: .275s;

  transition: .275s;
}
.menu-hamburger__line {
  top: 2px;

  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);

       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);

          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .275s;
       -o-transition-duration: .275s;
          transition-duration: .275s;
}

.menu-hamburger__lines::before,
.menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  content: '';

  display: block;
}
.menu-hamburger__lines::before {
  top: 10px;

  -webkit-transition: opacity .125s ease .275s;

  -o-transition: opacity .125s ease .275s;

  transition: opacity .125s ease .275s;
}
.menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  top: 20px;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);

  transition: -webkit-transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);

  -o-transition: transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);

  transition: transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);

  transition: transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55), -webkit-transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55);
}

.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines,
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::after,
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::before {
  background-color: #033071;
}
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms;
       -o-transition-delay: 75ms;
          transition-delay: 75ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,10px,0) rotate(135deg);
          transform: translate3d(0,10px,0) rotate(135deg);
}
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
       -o-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms;
       -o-transition-delay: 75ms;
          transition-delay: 75ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0) rotate(-270deg);
          transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0) rotate(-270deg);
}
/*******/

.main-nav__item.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-child {
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: -100%; */
  left: 0;

  width: 30rem;

  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0;

  background: #c4f2f7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #444;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #444;

  list-style: none;

  text-align: left;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;

      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;

          transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
          transform: scaleY(0);

  -webkit-transition: .3s;

  -o-transition: .3s;

  transition: .3s;

  z-index: 3;
}

.main-nav__item.parent:hover .nav-child {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
          transform: scaleY(1);
}

.nav-child .main-nav__item {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.nav-child .main-nav__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.main-menu__item--parent > .main-menu-submenu > .main-menu__item.item-326 a{
    margin-top: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #04ccff;
}
.main-menu__item--parent > .main-menu-submenu > .main-menu__item.item-326 a:hover {
    color:#000;

}

.main-menu__item--parent > .main-menu-submenu  .main-menu__item.item-326 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.main-menu > .main-menu__item.item-326 a:hover {
    border-color: #000;
}
.main-menu__item--parent::after {
content: '';
margin-left: .25rem;
border-top: 0.35em solid;
border-right: 0.35em solid transparent;
border-left: 0.35em solid transparent;
border-bottom: 0;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
color:#fff;
}

.main-menu__item--parent .main-menu-submenu a {
  color: #fc6a20!important;
}

.main-menu__item--parent .main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item a{
  color: #333!important;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если интересно, что добавил/поменял, поиск по слову "replace" и "push"

```css
body {
  background-color: #845084;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav__close {
  display: none;
}

.main-menu>.main-menu__item {
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.main-menu>.main-menu__item:hover {}

.main-menu>.main-menu__item a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-menu a::after {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  /* bottom: -1px; */
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  background: #fc6a20;
}

.main-menu a:hover::after {
  width: 25px;
}

.main-menu-submenu a::after {
  left: 23px;
}

.main-menu>.main-menu__item a:hover {}

.main-menu>.main-menu__item.active {}

.main-menu__item--parent {
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu-submenu {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  min-width: 16rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}


/* Заголовки в подменю в каталоге (синенькие) */

.main-menu__item--parent>.main-menu-submenu>.main-menu__item>a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: block;
}


/* Серые кнопки подменю в каталоге */

.main-menu__item--parent>.main-menu-submenu>.main-menu__item>.main-menu-submenu a {
  background: #fff;
  /* padding: .6rem 1.5rem; */
}

.main-menu__item.item-127--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-128--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-149--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-162--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-175--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-200--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-225--parent>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-127>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-128>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-149>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-162>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-175>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-200>a:after,
.main-menu__item.item-225>a:after {
  /* top: 8px;
      right: 9px;
      font-size: 11px;
      content: "\f105";
      position: absolute;
      font-weight: 400;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: FontAwesome; */
  display: none;
}

.main-menu-submenu>.main-menu__item:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover>.main-menu-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  /* flex-direction: column; replace */
  min-width: 20rem;
}

.main-menu__item--parent>.main-menu-submenu {
  min-width: 20rem;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover>.main-menu-submenu:hover {}

.main-menu__item.item-123:hover>.main-menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  width: 94rem;
  height: 51rem;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #777;
  margin-left: -20rem
}

.main-menu__item.item-123>.main-menu-submenu {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/*
  .main-menu__item.item-123 > .main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item > a {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  } */

.main-menu__item.item-123:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123 .main-menu-submenu {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123>.main-menu-submenu:hover {
  background: inherit;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123>.main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu.small {
  position: static;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: auto;
  width: 16rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.main-menu__item.item-123>.main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu.small .main-menu__item {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #05a3cb;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover>.main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .6rem 1.5rem;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover>.main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
  /*push*/
  flex-direction: column;
  /*push*/
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  /*  left: 100%; */
  border: none;
}

.main-menu__item--parent:hover .main-menu-submenu {
  /* display: block;   replace*/
  display: flex;
  /*push*/
}


/*** Меню гамбургер ***/

.menu-hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: .5rem;
  right: .5rem;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .15s;
  -o-transition-duration: .15s;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: opacity, -webkit-filter;
  -o-transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-property: opacity, filter, -webkit-filter;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-hamburger__lines,
.menu-hamburger__lines::before,
.menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #033071;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -o-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition: .275s;
  -o-transition: .275s;
  transition: .275s;
}

.menu-hamburger__line {
  top: 2px;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .275s;
  -o-transition-duration: .275s;
  transition-duration: .275s;
}

.menu-hamburger__lines::before,
.menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.menu-hamburger__lines::before {
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .125s ease .275s;
  -o-transition: opacity .125s ease .275s;
  transition: opacity .125s ease .275s;
}

.menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  transition: -webkit-transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  transition: transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
  transition: transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55), -webkit-transform .275s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55);
}

.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines,
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::after,
.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::before {
  background-color: #033071;
}

.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms;
  -o-transition-delay: 75ms;
  transition-delay: 75ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0) rotate(135deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0) rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-hamburger.is-active .menu-hamburger__lines::after {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms;
  -o-transition-delay: 75ms;
  transition-delay: 75ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0) rotate(-270deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0) rotate(-270deg);
}


/*******/

.main-nav__item.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-child {
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: -100%; */
  left: 0;
  width: 30rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
  background: #c4f2f7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #444;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #444;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index: 3;
}

.main-nav__item.parent:hover .nav-child {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.nav-child .main-nav__item {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-child .main-nav__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main-menu__item--parent>.main-menu-submenu>.main-menu__item.item-326 a {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #04ccff;
}

.main-menu__item--parent>.main-menu-submenu>.main-menu__item.item-326 a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.main-menu__item--parent>.main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item.item-326 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.main-menu>.main-menu__item.item-326 a:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}

.main-menu__item--parent::after {
  content: '';
  margin-left: .25rem;
  border-top: 0.35em solid;
  border-right: 0.35em solid transparent;
  border-left: 0.35em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-menu__item--parent .main-menu-submenu a {
  color: #fc6a20!important;
}

.main-menu__item--parent .main-menu-submenu .main-menu-submenu .main-menu__item a {
  color: #333!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-menu__item item-120">
      <a href="/o-kompanii">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-menu__item item-184 deeper main-menu__item--parent">
      <a href="#">Продукция</a>
      <ul class="main-menu-submenu unstyled small ">
        <li class="main-menu__item item-185 active deeper main-menu__item--parent">
          <a href="/filtry-dlya-ochistnykh-sooruzhenij">Фильтры для очистных сооружений</a>
          <ul class="main-menu-submenu unstyled small ">
            <li class="main-menu__item item-187">
              <a href="/osvetlitelnye-sorbtsionnye">Фильтры напорные осветлительные сорбционные</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item item-189">
              <a href="/glubokoj-ochistki">Фильтры напорные глубокой очистки</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item item-188">
              <a href="/kombinirovannye">Фильтры безнапорные комбинированные</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item item-190">
              <a href="/glubokoj-ochistki">Фильтры безнапорные глубокой очистки </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu__item item-186 deeper main-menu__item--parent">
          <a href="/filtry-dlya-nasosnykh-stantsij">Фильтры для насосных станций</a>
          <ul class="main-menu-submenu unstyled small ">
            <li class="main-menu__item item-191">
              <a href="/produktsiya/category-2/filtr-ov-5">Фильтр ОВ-5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item item-192">
              <a href="/produktsiya/category-2/ezhektor-s-konicheskoj-nasadkoj">Эжектор с конической насадкой</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-menu__item item-127">
      <a href="/sertifikaty">Сертификаты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-menu__item item-119">
      <a href="/kontakty">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```